# Java slow class Loadtime when launched in rapid succession [JDK1.6]

Tags: java, linux, java-6

I have currently troubles with java processes taking more and more time to load.

I've searched around and came across the `"-verbose"` option of the JVM. It gives me something like that :

```
1400 [Loaded sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$URLSeedGenerator$1 from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/lib/rt.jar]
1401 [Loaded sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1 from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/lib/rt.jar]
<----Several seconds here --->
1402 [Loaded sun.nio.cs.US_ASCII$Encoder from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/lib/rt.jar]
1403 [Loaded sun.nio.cs.Surrogate$Parser from /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

Is the loading of this `class => Loaded sun.nio.cs.US_ASCII$Encoder` really the culptit here ?

The "several second" part may seem insignificant, since I did not say "minutes" but there are several javas run in succession and it adds up to a considerable amount of time for each iteration of the entire process (which runs all day).

The problem seems to happen only when two javas are launched in close succession one after the other.

To test this, I run the program once, and when it exits, I run it again. The first time runs usually without stopping, but the second time it stops for several seconds

Thank you in advance for any time you might take helping me.

Comment: this is too broad. i'm not sure the exact problem but you can check if when a new app is starting, does the old one stop? if not, they may be competing for CPU, memory or IO.

Comment: Hello gigadot,I have edited the post to reflect what I have done. Both processes do not run simultaneously, although other processes may run on the server, it is a general application server

Comment: Almost certainly `SeedGenerator` loaded when something in your program initialized a `SecureRandom`. This requires **obtaining entropy from the environment**, and depending on the OS and possibly hardware you're running on and the state it's in and how your JVM/JRE is configured, collecting entropy may take some time. If you are on recent LInux, *usually* it should just work unless someone has tried to 'improve' it. On other systems, if EGD (Entropy Gathering Demon) exists but is not installed and configured and running, doing that usually helps.

Comment: Hello Dave, I cannot thank you enough. I have looked on the internet starting from what you said, and have added -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom the shell running each process, and the problem does not seem to occur anymore. Any reasons why I should not use this option ? Please also point me at the thing to accept your answer because I cannot find it on the page :)

Comment: Also, any idea why the line : Loaded sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1 shows up before the delay whereas it should be after ? I guess it should be spelled "Loading" and not "Loaded"